# Apache 2.2 redirect all but one directory

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, rewrite

I have this in my `httpd.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost IP.AD.DR.ESS:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect Permanent / https://example.net/
</VirtualHost>
```

This is successfully redirecting everything formerly at `http://example.com` to its new corresponding location at `https://example.net`.  However, I've discovered one directory, `example.com/specialdir/`, has to stay on the old server since the data it needs to access isn't on the new server.  (It's going to take *months* to finish the migration involving a couple dozen other sites.)

Is there a reasonable way to fix this in `httpd.conf` or am I going to have to use a bunch of `.htaccess` files?  I suspect there's something I can do with `<Location>` containers, but I don't know the right question to ask to find the information.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can modify the `Redirect` directive to instead make use of a [`RedirectMatch`](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/mod_alias#redirectmatch) and use a pattern excluding `/specialdir`:

```
RedirectMatch Permanent "^(/(?!specialdir/).*)" https://example.net/$1
```

Comment: You saved me from pulling out the rest of my hair ;)

Comment: It works, but it was adding a double slash for some reason, so had to do it like: `https://example.net$1`

Comment: I was getting double slashes as well. Plus had to exclude two folders, so I did this:
`RedirectMatch permanent "^(/(?!(files1/|files2/)).*)" https://www.example.com$1` Likewise word `permanent` can be replaced by `301` which is same, or with `302` which means temporary redirect. Thanks for the answer!